# Can we run CLang 3.3 and C 0x lib on Mac OS 10.6 ?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang

I am able to run basic constructs of C++11,  such as auto variables in CLang 3.3

But when it comes to assignment_initialization such as

```
 vector<int> v={1,2};
```

I get error from CLang++ saying I should include

```
<initializer_list>
```

But when I do use it, it says file not found for "initializer_list"

Anywork around or any solution ?

Comment: Works fine here, I'm using from trunk a very recent snapshot.

Comment: oh, I didn't noticed it was about an specific OS X version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C++11 library features you need libc++, and that is supported by Apple only on 10.7 and forward.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from building libc++ from source though. :)